# VSTS Build Agents using Azure Scale Sets

Tags: azure-devops

I am helping someone that has a build agent in Azure. The build agent is in Azure to allow the build to leverage the connection between Azure and on-prem. The development team is starting to use VSTS heavily and therefore the build agent as well. The idea is to create another build agent in Azure to help with the growing workload.

Can a Build Agent be installed in an Azure Scale Set so that it can scale out and in as needed?

I have installed the Build Agent on Scale Sets but I am not getting the relevant objects back using the Build Variables. So is it possible?

Thank you
Julio

Comment: What do you mean you can not get the relevant objects back using the Build Variables?

Comment: What I mean is that when I use a variable such as $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)or $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) it is not finding any objects. Maybe I need to make sure that the load balance has sticky sessions turned on.

Comment: Can you access the system environment variable during build/release?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm trying to do the same thing but it only seems to register one agent - probably a naming conflict